# C# MongoDB "Near" Query

Tags: linq, c#-4.0, collections, mongodb-.net-driver

I have a mongo collection that look like that:

```
{
"_id": {
    "$oid": "50e9f38fbd7680c8090bcb4"
},
"guid": "D3G5wQ8RZL",
"lat": 37.503287248864,
"lng": -121.97620341421,
```

}
I want to preform "NEAR" query using C# linq

it need to look something like that

```
query = query.Where(x => LinqToMongo.Inject(Query.Near("Location", -96.770401, 32.816774, 20)));
```

MY question is - What should I code insted of "Location"? how can I check the Points from the collection above?

Thanks.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

As of MongoDB 2.4, store and index GeoJSON. You can find all the concepts [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/applications/geospatial-indexes/).

How to define a GeoJSON property on a POCO type:

```
public class Foo
{
  public GeoJsonPoint<GeoJson2DGeographicCoordinates> Location { get; set; }
}
```

An example instantiation:

```
var docToInsert = new Foo
            {   
                Location = new GeoJsonPoint<GeoJson2DGeographicCoordinates>(
                    new GeoJson2DGeographicCoordinates(-121.97620341421, 37.503287248864))
            });
```

[$near](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/near/) requires a geospatial index, and since we're storing GeoJSON, it specifically requires a 2dsphere index:

```
var collection = //get MongoCollection<Foo> from MongoDatabase object
collection.EnsureIndex(IndexKeys<Foo>.GeoSpatialSpherical(x => x.Location));
```

Now the query:

```
var point = GeoJson.Point(GeoJson.Geographic(-96.770401, 32.816774)); //long, lat

var locationClause = Query<Foo>.Near(y=> y.Location, point, 20); //20 is max distance from your question. note that it's in meters
IQueryable<Foo> query = collection.AsQueryable().Where( x=> locationClause.Inject()); 

//or with the non-generic Query:  
IQueryable<Foo> query = collection.AsQueryable().Where( x=> Query.Near("Location", point, 20).Inject());
```

Comment: What is the namespace of Query?

Comment: I have tried this code but got error on Inject() Method like missing assembly how can I resolve this, I searched on the google but did not found the namespace

Comment: Above query is resolved, but when run the code got an error:"The LinqToMongo.Inject method is only intended to be used in LINQ Where clauses"

Comment: I'm having the same problem as Singh: "The LinqToMongo.Inject method is only intended to be used in LINQ Where clauses"

Comment: @Singh - I am having same error -  The LinqToMongo.Inject method is only intended to be used in LINQ Where clauses - did you find a resolution to that?

Comment: @D.Reagan - I am having same error - The LinqToMongo.Inject method is only intended to be used in LINQ Where clauses - did you find a resolution to that?

Comment: @Singh  the namespace is MongoDB.Driver.Linq

Comment: The way I accomplish the query Mongo 2.8:

var point = GeoJson.Point(GeoJson.Geographic(-96.770401, 32.816774)); 
var locationQuery = new FilterDefinitionBuilder<Foo>().Near(tag => tag.Location, point, 20);
var c = collection.Find(locationQuery).ToList();